# R: Using optim() to set variable weights

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(matrix(rexp(45), 5))
data <- cbind(data, c(1,2,2,3,1))
colnames(data) <- c("model1_a","model1_b","model1_c","model2_a","model2_b","model2_c","model3_a","model3_b","model3_c", "true_max")
```

That is:

```
   model1_a  model1_b  model1_c  model2_a  model2_b   model2_c   model3_a  model3_b  model3_c true_max
1 0.7551818 2.8949685 1.3907351 1.0352439 2.3645153 0.05943916 1.43528534 1.0227259 1.0798811        1
2 1.1816428 1.2295621 0.7620299 1.8760352 0.6418926 0.57871246 0.03726853 0.3017409 1.0282469        2
3 0.1457067 0.5396828 1.2376036 0.6547466 0.2941204 3.95893285 0.32401015 0.7252143 1.2922616        2
4 0.1397953 0.9565675 4.4239342 0.3369335 0.5658655 1.17331211 1.32046793 0.7515427 1.2531054        3
5 0.4360686 0.1470460 1.0545432 0.5884797 0.1060726 0.99681296 0.20351035 0.2350275 0.5546414        1
```

Using this data, I need to find the optimal weights for combining the results from each model. Without weights, these sums are:

```
  cbind(
    "a_total" = data$model1_a+data$model2_a+data$model3_a,
    "b_total" = data$model1_b+data$model2_b+data$model3_b,
    "c_total" = data$model1_c+data$model2_c+data$model3_c
  )

      a_total   b_total  c_total
[1,] 3.225711 6.2822097 2.530055
[2,] 3.094946 2.1731956 2.368989
[3,] 1.124464 1.5590175 6.488798
[4,] 1.797197 2.2739757 6.850352
[5,] 1.228059 0.4881461 2.605998
```

Using `which.max()` yields the estimated max of `2 1 3 3 3`. 
How do I use `optim()` to set weights to each column (or individual value)? The data contains the true max.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
# weights
# model1_a  model1_b  model1_c  model2_a  model2_b   model2_c   model3_a  model3_b  model3_c
# W1        W2        W3        W4        W5         W6         1-W1-W4   1-W2-W5   1-W3-W6    

# max(data_model_i%*%W_model_i), i=1,2,3
model.opt <- function (W,data) {
  max(sum(data[,c(1,4,7)]*c(W[1],W[4],1-W[1]-W[4])),
      sum(data[,c(2,5,8)]*c(W[2],W[5],1-W[2]-W[5])),
      sum(data[,c(3,6,9)]*c(W[3],W[6],1-W[3]-W[6])))
}

for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  W <- optim(par=rep(0.5,6), fn = model.opt, 
          method = "L-BFGS-B",
          lower = rep(0,6), # W_i >= 0 for all i
          upper = rep(1,6), # W_i <= 1 for all i
          control = list(fnscale = -1), 
          data=as.matrix(data[i,]))$par # optimum W
  print(which.max(c(sum(data[i,c(1,4,7)]*c(W[1],W[4],1-W[1]-W[4])),
      sum(data[i,c(2,5,8)]*c(W[2],W[5],1-W[2]-W[5])),
      sum(data[i,c(3,6,9)]*c(W[3],W[6],1-W[3]-W[6])))))
}

[1] 2
[1] 1
[1] 3
[1] 3
[1] 3
```

Comment: Thank you. But this code doesn't optimize towards the values given by in column `true_max`, right?

Comment: no it does not @Joshua, how did you obtain the values for true_max? perhaps the way the weights are combined (e.g., combining all the weights  for the 'a's together) is not the right way?

Comment: The data shown is my training data, this data should be used to set the weights. Can you help me make this updated function to be optimized? I tried to, but didn't find a way (to compare the true_max to the weighted row-wise max)

Comment: does model1_a always need to be combined with model2_a and model3_a or we can combine model1_a with model1_b also? Is there any constraint that we need to combine 3 of them at a time (so that the sum of the weights is 1, as it appears from your example)?

Comment: The example data has 3 models predicting the probability of the 3 categories (a,b,c). For example, a=high risk, b=medium risk and c=low risk. If one of the models has a low correlation with risk, its weight should be low, or zero. The weights do not have to add up to 1. Each row is one observation, and I need to predict which category is the likeliest.